# how to go to new activity when an item is clicked in listview?

Tags: java, android

how to add `onitemclicklistner` in the post execution:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // Hiding the progress bar after done loading JSON.
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // Showing the ListView after done loading JSON.
    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // Setting up the SubjectArrayList into Array Adapter.
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
                          android.R.id.text1, 
                          SubjectArrayList);

    // Passing the Array Adapter into ListView.
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Comment: You can set `onitemclicklistner` in `onCreate()` (If Activity) . Or in same you can set in `onPostExecute()` .

Comment: Let your class `implements` `Onitemclicklistner` and set it as `listView.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);`

Comment: Why do you create the adapter in onPostExecute?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Implement your logic, you will get clicked position of view
            }
        });
```

Comment: i had already tried the code that you mentioned above but after clicking the item in listview the app stops working